# Shiny daterange input causes app to crash when 5 digit year is entered on IE

Tags: r, shiny, internet-explorer-9

In internet explorer IE9, the application crashes instantly when a 5 year digit is inputted. It doesn't happen in chrome.

ui.R

```
fluidPage(

# Copy the line below to make a date range selector
dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Date range")),

hr(),
fluidRow(column(4, verbatimTextOutput("value")))

)
```

server.R

```
function(input, output) {

# You can access the values of the widget (as a vector of Dates)
# with input$dates, e.g.
output$value <- renderPrint({ input$dates })

}
```

Comment: Do you have any questions about this?

Comment: Yes, how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: Can reproduce in Firefox 49.0.1; when manually typing a 5-digit year into the left input field of the date range, the app throws an error: `Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

Comment: The error appears even if there is no server code at all, i.e. it must be linked to `dateRangeInput()` only.

Comment: This is probably better posted to the Shiny github repo issues